# Доступ к обьектам коллекции

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сравнить элементы коллекции каждый с каждым? Немного обьясню, у меня есть метод, который работает с двумя обьектами, вызываю его так objectname.method(objectname1)в цикле foreach, но получаеться, что я беру один и тот же обьект, а должно быть два разных.

Comment: Ну а цикл `for` почему не используете?

Comment: а как вы их хотите сравнивать? Один больше или меньше другого? Или равны ли они? Сортировка в коллекции нужна?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Под сравнением понимается вызов objectname.method(objectname1)?

Answer (score 0):

Имейте ввиду, что если используете ссылочные типы данных, то при сравнении сравниваются ссылки, а не сами объекты. Для сравнения объектов нужно писать свой компаратор, который будет сравнивать их на основе конкретных полей типа.

Для сравнения можете использовать класс `Tuple<T>`.

Можете сравнивать структуры, в них идет сравнение по значению, а не по ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Увы, я не обладаю телепатическими способностями, но судя по всему Вам нужно, что-то вроде этого

```
        List<MyClass> lst = new List<MyClass>();

        lst.Add(new MyClass(1));
        lst.Add(new MyClass(2));
        lst.Add(new MyClass(3));
        lst.Add(new MyClass(4));

        for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < lst.Count; j++)
            {
                int compareResult = lst[i].method(lst[j]);
            }
        }
```